# Tkinter to get directory from a network

Tags: python, tkinter

**Scenario:** I am trying get some file paths to use further down my code. For that I am using tkinter and the askdirectory function to allow the user to make the folder selection. The code below works normally to find folders in my computer, but in this case I would like to access a folder in a network.

From other questions and the tkinter documentation, I got to this code:

```
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askdirectory

Tk().withdraw()
sourcefolder = askdirectory()
outputfolder = askdirectory()
```

**Question:** Is it possible to use tkinter to retrieve a path form a network? If not, is there another API that can do this?

Comment: Well I just tested `askdirectory()` and I was able to pull up a file path on the network in some share drives. Can you add some context to what exactly you are attempting?

Comment: @Mike-SMT I am just trying to open one folder in the network and get its path, nothing major, but for some reason, when I click the network folder in the dialogbox, it shows as empty.

Comment: Yes mine does show as empty as well but it does pick up share drives that have been mapped to my PC. I will see if there is another option but in the interim can you map that folder to your PC and then use askdirectory?

Comment: Absolutely. will try that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So eventhough you may not see the network paths when expanding `Network` in the `askdirectory()` you can set a default into a Network path.

In the below example if you tell `askdirectory()` to default to some path in a network drive you will be able to use it.

Update:
after some digging and testing on my end my below example works as long as you have the exact path to the share folder you have access to. If you only path to the server you may not go anywhere as your access may be restricted to a specific folder. Try to make sure you are for sure got the exact share drive. On our servers it is not case sensitive but yours might be so make sure you follow that as well or test both accurate casing and all lower to see like I have.

What I did was type my path directly into the windows folder view to make sure it was a valid path and then copy that into my code.

Keep in mind there are a few ways you can set up your text to work. All the following formats have worked for me:

```
r"\\server_complete_name_here\share_folder_name" # normalizing the string
"\\\\server_complete_name_here\\share_folder_name" # escaping the backslashes
"//server_complete_name_here/share_folder_name" # windows can take forward slashes
"\\\\server_complete_name_here/share_folder_name" # mixing it up.
```

Example code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

myApp=Tk()

outputfolder = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=myApp, initialdir=r"\\server_complete_name_here\share_folder_name")

myApp.mainloop()
```

If that doesn't work for you then you may also map a dive to your local PC and then `askdirectory()` will be able to see it.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with my version of tkinter, because it shows a very basic dialog window and it does not go to the default directory for some reason.

Comment: Well maybe. Depending on how your network security is set up you may not be able to access the network share with a default path but instead only as a mapped drive. If you are on a home PC but do not have network discovery turned on it wont work. If you are in a company environment there may be security policies in play preventing the viewing of the network servers.

Comment: @DGMS89 did some more looking around and testing on my end. See my updated text.